# l want to send live camera from phone 1 to phone 2 via wifi

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

l want to send live camera from phone 1 to phone 2 via wifi. What is the easiest way to do this ?
I Can sending my voice  from phone 1 to phone 2 successful. but I can not send live camera to phon2. 
I found " libstreaming " and " Sipdroid " that Used for communication stream(audio or live camera )  Between two devices. But I do not understand them And it is very difficult. 
Is there an easier way to do it ?

the code of voice receive

```
        Thread receiveThread = new Thread (new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {



               //minimum buffer size. need to be careful. might cause problems. try setting manually if any problems faced
               int minBufSize =AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat)*2;

               speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC ,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,1600,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

               speaker.play();

                try {

                    DatagramSocket socket1 = new DatagramSocket(9000);
                    log2( "Socket Created");

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1600];

                   while( true) {


                            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,1600);
                            socket1.receive(packet);


                            log2("Packet data read into buffer");

                            speaker.write(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());

                            log2("Writing buffer content to speaker");


                    }


                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    log2("SocketException");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

        });
        receiveThread.start();
```

the code of voice send

```
 Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                try {


                        int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat)*10;


                       log2("Socket Created");

                  DatagramPacket packet;

                  final InetAddress destination = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.49.1");



                       recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,minBufSize);
                       log2("Recorder initialized");



                       byte[] buffer = new byte[1600];


                       recorder.startRecording();

                       int bytes_read = 0;
                       DatagramSocket socket1 = new DatagramSocket();

                        while(true) {


                            //reading data from MIC into buffer
                            bytes_read = recorder.read(buffer, 0, 1600);
                            //putting buffer in the packet
                            packet = new DatagramPacket (buffer, bytes_read,destination,9000);


                            socket1.send(packet);

                        }


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //Log.e("VS", "IOException");
                    } 


               }

            });
            streamThread.start();
```

The above code is for Send and receive voice.. But i want a simple way for sending camera live from phone 1 to another... please help me..

Comment: Can you please share the code of sending voice from one phone to another using wifi ?

Comment: I used this   "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183963/two-way-streaming-voice-between-android-phones-over-wi-fi"   my question is about live camera  transmission.....

Comment: Thanks, but can you send me that working code ?

Comment: Ok. I put the code into the top of the page ..